# DB2 - difference between two timestamp in days

Tags: db2

how to get exact difference between two timestamp in days in DB2. I mean if one date is FROM_DATE=5/6/2015 2:22:27.000000 PM and TO_DATE=3/30/2015 2:33:52.000000 PM, then the timestamp difference should show 36 days. I tried using below

```
((24*DAYS(From_Date)+MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(From_Date)/3600) -

        (24*DAYS(To_Date)+MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(To_Date)/3600))/(24)
```

But this is giving me the difference as 37 days.

Comment: You do `MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(n) / 3600`, which means your method has a "resolution" of one hour.  Your times have the same hour, so cancel each other out.  After that, `37` seems correct (March: 1 day, April: 30 days, May: 6 days), although I would consider the _direction_ to be backwards (that is, you should be getting `-37`).  Fixing your issue requires taking seconds and fractional seconds into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT days_between ('2015-05-06-02.22.27.000000', '2015-03-30-02.33.52.000000')
FROM SYSIBM.sysdummy1
```

It returns 36.

Comment: ... how does this handle spans over multiple months?  If `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is being used as the source under the covers it would royally screw you over (which is why you have to use OP's version on some older systems).

Comment: Seems, that [days_between](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061477.html) handles all possible dates correctly. It returns the same output as `(
  (DAYS(From_Date)*bigint(86400) + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(From_Date))
- (DAYS(To_Date)  *bigint(86400) + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(To_Date))
)/86400`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong formula. Check out the following.

```
SELECT
  FROM_DATE, TO_DATE
,
(
  (24*DAYS(From_Date)+MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(From_Date)/3600) 
- (24*DAYS(To_Date)+MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(To_Date)/3600)
)/24 AS D1
, 
(
  (DAYS(From_Date)*bigint(86400) + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(From_Date))
- (DAYS(To_Date)  *bigint(86400) + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(To_Date))
)/86400 AS D2
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  (TIMESTAMP('2015-05-06-14.22.27'), TIMESTAMP('2015-03-30-14.33.52'))
, (TIMESTAMP('2015-03-31-14.22.27'), TIMESTAMP('2015-03-30-14.33.52'))
, (TIMESTAMP('2015-04-01-14.22.27'), TIMESTAMP('2015-03-30-14.33.52'))
) T(FROM_DATE, TO_DATE);

|FROM_DATE                 |TO_DATE                   |D1         |D2                  |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|-----------|--------------------|
|2015-05-06-14.22.27.000000|2015-03-30-14.33.52.000000|37         |36                  |
|2015-03-31-14.22.27.000000|2015-03-30-14.33.52.000000|1          |0                   |
|2015-04-01-14.22.27.000000|2015-03-30-14.33.52.000000|2          |1                   |
```